# Get output of different controller action in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, get

For generating PDF from HTML, i need to fill a variable with output from another controller action output (HTML). Is there any elegant way, how to get this HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
def print
  output = render_to_string(:action => :index)
end
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You may abstract the code in that action into a shared method which would be called within your pdf-generating action.

After calling the shared method, you would get the html page content like this:

```
pdf_content = ERB.new(File.read("/path/to/that/erb.file")).result
```